# C# / Objective-C Extendable Application (Application that can be modified through extensions)

Tags: c#, objective-c, extending

I'm looking into extending my C# application (and its Objective-C counterpart) to allow user created extensions to be loaded and utilized.

The idea would be that loaded extensions could either 'decorate' the output, or replace the driving mechanism entirely. For example, the application I am working on outputs colors based off the logic defined in each operating mode. A decorator extension would be something like converting to grayscale, or upping the saturation, where the built-in mode would generate the color and the extension modifies the result. While a driver extension would act like its own mode outputting colors on its own.

What design paradigms work well for this sort of problem?

Answer (score 0):

The "Managed Extensibility Framework" will help you a lot with the C# version of your app:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

This is a library that Microsoft created for situations like the one you're in.

But I know next-to-nothing about Objective-C, so I can't offer any help with that.